# Bosch grass strimmer - change nylon string cutter for solid wire cutter

Tags: weed-control

Have Bosch grass strimmer equips with nylon cord cutter. Would like to change the nylon reel for one of the numerous wire disc strimmer attachments but not sure how to set about it.

Comment: a picture of the trimmer head would help...